# Impersonation in office365 API to perform calendar related operations using single account

Tags: c#, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

Is there any way to perform impersonation in office365 rest API's similar like [impersonation in EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx). I tried creating a sample application based on this [link](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet).  Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not impersonation, but you can authenticate as an application with access to all calendars in the organization. An org admin has to consent to the app. Read more here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/